# Flask. Не скачивается файл

Tags: flask

Хочу сделать скачивание файла по ссылке(e.g. site.ru/demo.docx)

Вот такой код:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'C:\\Users\\Haska\\PycharmProjects\\Quiz_v1'

@app.route('/<filename>')
def get_doc(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename)
```

Ошибка 404